# M2: Issue during creating landing page

Tags: magento2, landing-pages

I created folder **< root >/access** and here put template files landing page.

Now this landing page is runing from **index.html**

http://b2bstyle.pl/access/

Ok, looks like everything is ok.

**Step 2**

Now I go to magento `back end` --> `content` and `create page`

Now I copy all contect from index.html and put in magento back-end
[image]

Of course, in this code I changed location to `.js` and `.css` and `img` by add before link, our folder name `access/`

**Ok, now we try open this page we create before in backend:**
https://b2bstyle.pl/dostep

But impossible, still loading....

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement HTML this way.

You have to follow Magento 2 frontend architecture.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html

You have to knowledge of **Layout and templates, Less, knockout Js,require JS**.

You have used the basic way to include js to the system, You cannot add js at this way at magento2.

So, follow magento2 frontend architecture.

Comment: Does this require big changes in files? I am a beginner so if it will require a lot of changes then I will have to look for a different solution.

Comment: I little changed now our page and add content in magento: https://b2bstyle.pl/dostep but still little wrong: should be: http://hurtownia.b2bstyle.pl/ Can you please help us solve this issue?